# Help identifying math notations

Tags: calculus, notation

while researching how some financial indices are calculated, I came across two math notations that I cannot identify, can anyone please help? A picture of the equation is available below:

[the half triangle-looking thing on top of askPV(v) and the square bracket with the open bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvF9u.png)

Link to the index methodology in question: [LINK](https://docs.cfbenchmarks.com/CME%20CF%20Real%20Time%20Indices%20Methodology.pdf)

Comment: We call them "hat" and "ceiling," respectively.

Comment: Welcome to Math SE! Feel free to take the [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) and look at the [guidelines](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) . Your question should be self-contained, providing all information required to understand it. Also, please make sure to use MathJAX for typing math. Thanks!

Comment: @SeanRoberson does the "hat" operator denote a set? because to the best of my understanding the askPV is the ask side of the order book which can have many volumes at different price levels.

Comment: I don't know what the context of these things are (and I definitely have no knowledge of quantitative finance). Symbols can be use to build something new in context - for example, given a well-behaved function $f$, we can denote its Fourier transform by $\hat{f}.$ You'll have to dig into the meaning in the paper itself.

Comment: @SeanRoberson Thank you so much for your help, i truly appreciate it. Ive also added a link to the index methodology if you are interested!

Comment: @Matija I think we can allow an exemption to the general "use MathJax" rule in this case, since an asker who doesn't know the name of a symbol is unlikely to know its MathJax command.

Comment: @Jam: Fair point! In this case, maybe posting the relevant screenshot directly would be an option? You know, because external links might pose a security threat (for inexperienced users). Just a train of thought :-) Speaking of external links: [This](https://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) is a great resource to learn commands and names for symbols.

Comment: @Jam thank you that's a great resource! i tried adding the screenshots as a picture to the post but it automatically turned it into a link. my apologies I'm not experienced with using this platform!

Comment: @medulink11 Any mathematical paper that expects the reader to know what $\widehat{\quad}$ means is an example of dubiousness. Luckily the authors of your paper define $\widehat{askPV}_T(v)$ just two lines above that equation in your image. Namely in ***Eq. 1a.***